# Excel iterate through worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with many sheets and into some I need to enter a value if the preceding cell matches a given string.

My code works for the sheets I need it to but it errors out when it reaches some non desired sheets (that also have data in them).

The line the Debugger highlights is `For Each r In Intersect (ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("F:F")` I'm a newbie with VBA/Excel scripting. Sorry if this is blindingly obvious but I searched the site and couldn't find an answer that fit, or I just didn't recognize it.

```
Sub AllOnePool()
    Dim myStr As String
    Dim myPool As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation

    myStr = InputBox(Prompt:="Input the Target Serial Number: e.g. 93127")
    myPool = InputBox(Prompt:="Input the Pool to Use: ")

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Activate
        For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("F:F"))
            If r.Text = myStr Then
                r.Offset(0, 1) = myPool
            End If
        Next r
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Really tangential, but unless the Serial Number is always 93127 (which would raise another set of questions) then your "i.e." should be "e.g." http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ie-versus-eg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check that the 2 ranges intersect:

```
Sub AllOnePool()
    Dim myStr As String
    Dim myPool As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim xIng As Range

    myStr = InputBox(Prompt:="Input the Target Serial Number: i.e. 93127")
    myPool = InputBox(Prompt:="Input the Pool to Use: ")

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With sh
            Set xIng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("F:F"))
            If Not xIng Is Nothing Then
                For Each cel In xIng
                    If cel.Text = myStr Then cel.Offset(0, 1) = myPool
                Next
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Paul, but the remaining sheets also have content.

Comment: I changed validation of the intersect operation - it should eliminate the errors

Comment: Awesome, Paul. Any idea what I was doing wrong? Or is it just an excel thing?  Thanks again!

Comment: Column F was empty in some sheets (didn't have any used cells)